# Removing whitespaces after using .get_text() in python

Tags: python

I would like to remove the whitespaces from a bog standard .html file. I am using python 3.6.2

My code so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import logging
import textwrap

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print('opening file....')
with open("./scraped_pages/doc.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
    print('closing file...') 
    fp.close()
    print('..... file closed  ...')
    # print out the original text, in this case html source code
    # print(soup)   
    # only retrieve the text from the document, remove all html tags
    soup = soup.get_text()
    print(soup)

    lines = soup.split("\n")
    #Use the list comprehension syntax [line for line in lines if condition] with lines as the previous result and condition as line.strip() != "" to remove any empty lines from lines.
    no_soup = [line for line in lines if line.strip() != ""]

    # Declare an empty string and use a for-loop to iterate over the previous result. 
    no_empty_soup = ""
    # At each iteration, use the syntax str1 += str2 + "/n" to add the current element in the list str2 and a newline to the empty string str1.
    for line in no_soup:
        no_empty_soup += line + "\n"

    print("no empty lines:\n", no_empty_soup)

    soup = no_empty_soup.strip()
    print(soup)
    
   print(textwrap.dedent(soup))
```

and the doc.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
  <title>Head's title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="title"><b>Body's title</b></p>
  <p class="story">line begins
    <a href="http://example.com/element1" class="element" id="link1">1</a>
    <a href="http://example.com/element2" class="element" id="link2"> 2</a>
    <a href="http://example.com/avatar1" class="avatar" id="link3">3</a>
  <p>     line ends</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am getting returned

```
Head's title
Body's title
line begins
    1
 2
3
     line ends
```

and what I would like to get returned

```
Head's title,
Body's title
line begins
1
2
3
line ends
```

I do not understand why the white spaces remain after using `.strip()` or `textwrap.dedent()`.  If someone could explain please.

I would have expected the **'1'** to be at the first place on the line like **`B`** in **Body** and **`l`** in **line begins** after using `.get_text()`.  Any ideas, please?

Thank you,
Tommy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list comprehension is missing the `.strip()`, it should be:

```
no_soup = [line.strip() for line in lines if line.strip() != ""]
```

Then it'll work.

Comment: @ yvesonline  Yes, perfect.  Thank you

Comment: @  yvesonline  Actually, the first line still contains an initial whitespace, i.e. "  Head's title" instead of  "Head's title".  I can use `soup = no_empty_soup.strip()` to remove this space, though this might not be pythonic.

Comment: This space comes from the `print` call. When you do `print("no empty lines:\n", no_empty_soup)` Python separates the objects with a space, see the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). To avoid this change the print statement to `print("no empty lines:\n", no_empty_soup, sep="")`.

Comment: That being said `no_empty_soup` is your output without trailing or leading spaces on a per line basis, you don't need the `no_empty_soup.strip()`.

Comment: @ yvesonline Thank you.  Working as you suggest.